# Proper way to document a Class in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Given

```
function Just (x) {
    this.some = x;
    this.other = 1;
}
```

what is the most recommended way to document this class in JSDoc? (Take `x` to be a `string`).

Comment: It's a constructor, not a class. PS: http://usejsdoc.org/ PPS: show us your best attempt and let's go to [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @zerkms aren't the two synonymous?

Comment: @Todd: from what perspective? From perspective of a lot of people - yes. From the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) perspective - no.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Creates a new Just.
 * @class
 */
```

Source: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-class.html

Comment: What about parameters? What about members?

Comment: Yes, what about `x`,  `some` and `value`?

Comment: Inside every attribute should have his own jsdoc, you can be as declarative like you want and add extra tags like private, protected, overload, final